# Best way to remove unused using statements and order using statements in Xamarin Studio?

Tags: c#, xamarin, refactoring

What is the best way to remove unused using statements and order using statements with Xamarin Studio?

I want to have a tool or an extension/addin for Xamarin Studio to remove and sort using statements in **all** C# project files (on a MAC).

Some sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace DateInserter
{
    public enum DateInserterCommands
    {
        InsertDate,
    }
}
```

After refactoring:

```
namespace DateInserter
{
    public enum DateInserterCommands
    {
        InsertDate,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In Xamarin Studio you need to enable Code Analysis. When having done this, you can sort your using, remove unused sorting etc.

You can find it under preferences -> source analysis (enable both)

Comment: That only works for the currently opened file as opposed to **all** files as asked for.

Comment: any solution to modify on all files?